# Woocommerce - change default sorting by product tag

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce

I'm trying to change my current default sorting filter in WooCommerce to sort every product on every category by tag first and then by date. I've tried to glue something like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', 'jr_sorting_change' );

function jr_sorting_change( $sort_by ) {
    if( is_product_tag( 'my-tag' ) ) { 
        return 'date'; 
    }
    return $sort_by;
}
```

But it's not working. Do I missing something? Can someone tell me how can I do that and where I'm going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your case you are checking if you are on tag archive page to sort by date. You want to modify the query and for tags you will need sql

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the answer wont work. After some tests that will be a complicated sql to be written. I would recommend adding custom meta by which to sort your products . That meta can be automated as checking if product have tag 123 to add meta value for this product etc.